# Jasmine spy() for postMessage event failing

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I made a simple Jasmine test to call a spy from a postMessage but it fails.

What am I missing here?

```
it('Should trigger message event', function () {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('message');
    window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log(Object.keys(e), e.data); // this logs as expected
        spy();
    });
    window.postMessage('test', '*');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/4L9Vc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`postMessage` runs asynchronously, so you're hitting your expectation before the message has been posted and before the event can be fired off.

I rewrote your test like this and it works fine:

```
describe('Message', function () {
    
    var spy;
    
    beforeEach(function() {
        
        spy = jasmine.createSpy('message');
        
        window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
            console.log(Object.keys(e), e.data);
            spy();
        });
        
        window.postMessage('test', '*');
        
    });

    it('Should trigger message event', function () {
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    
});
```

It gets the job done here, but I don't know if it's the best solution because Jasmine provides us with the ability to test asynchronous methods: pre-2.0, you can use the `runs`, `waits`, and `waitsFor` methods ([source](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs)) and 2.0+ you can use the `done` method ([source](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)).

#### From MDN ([postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)):

> The window.postMessage method, when called, causes a MessageEvent to be dispatched at the target window when any pending script that must be executed completes.

Comment: And thank you for adding some more information to my answer! :)